# java.awt.print.PrinterException: Invalid name of PrintService

Tags: java, swing, printing, jfreereport

I would ask it in the form of a question, but I have no idea why I'm getting this exception. I can't find any real documentation online either.

To give you context although I don't think it's really relevant, I'm using it within the JFreeReport classic engine reporting framework.

The stacktrace is:

```
java.awt.print.PrinterException: Invalid name of PrintService.
    at sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob.setNativePrintService(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob.getPrintService(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob.printDialog(Unknown Source)
    at org.jfree.report.modules.gui.print.PrintUtil.print(PrintUtil.java:128)
    at org.jfree.report.modules.gui.print.PrintExportTask.run(PrintExportTask.java:84)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas or suggestions as to what's happening here would be greatly appreciated!

Update: It would be great to also find some documentation on where and when this error is generated...

Comment: What's the invalid PrintService name?

Comment: I'm still working on this issue, but I found an interesting Java bug report at: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=3b491a0d16afa70adb151ef43c89?bug_id=6788490

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Java just do not print my print job.

So I realised that, my company, just changed the main printer. Then I removed the old one from my printer's list (win 8) and set the new one as default.

Works like a charm!

PS: my first reply on stackoverflow! \o/

Answer (score 0):

The print service name should be the name of your printer. The PrintUtil class I am using at the moment brings up a dialog listing the printers I have setup in my operating system. Can you print from other applications using your computer?

If not you need to configure your printer, otherwise you may want to check if jFreeReport needs a default printer specified somewhere. Since JFreeReport is open source, you should be able to create a simple test program using just the PrintUtil class - that may make it easier to demonstrate what is going wrong with code.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to print from other applications on the computer.